# Cannot Display multiple results with different links In PHP

Tags: php, html, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I tried to use other ways but the result only displays one Link edit, since I have 3 kinds of Data/3 Persons, the edit links only shows to one person. I want to put 3 edit links with the same last name and will be updated later on the database.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","","logindb");

$search = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['search']);




$resultSet = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM precferm WHERE lname LIKE '$search%'");




if( $resultSet->num_rows > 0){
        while($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $lname = $rows ['lname'];
            $fname = $rows ['fname'];
            $mname = $rows ['mname'];

            $output =  " <a href=edit.php?id=$output> Edit</a><br /> Last Name: $lname<br />First Name: $fname<br />Middle Name: $mname<br /><br />";
        }
    }else{
            $output = "No results";

    }

}
```

Comment: This code is confusing:
1. What is the $output variable doing? and why it is used as an ID?
2. If you want to display three links, why don't you concatenate the string with other links?
3. Can you please post full snippet?

Comment: You are _overwriting_ `$output` in each loop iteration, so after the loop only the last value “survives”. You need to _append_ to the variable (that you initialized with an empty string before the loop), if you want to get such links for all three records.

Comment: could you show me the fetch_assoc() function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by [**CBroe** in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46294713/cannot-display-multiple-results-with-different-links-in-php#comment79552164_46294713):

> You are *overwriting* `$output` in each loop iteration, so after the loop only the last value “survives”. You need to *append* to the variable (that you initialized with an empty string before the loop), if you want to get such links for all three records.

So:
You can use a [PHP String operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) to Append strings, making your string contain more data with each iteration of the loop.

I have also used `"string".$var." more string"` to illustrate the other type of string operator (concatenation) (as well as best practise for variables withi a string setting).

```
$output = ""; // ensure value starts empty.

if( $resultSet->num_rows > 0){
        while($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $lname = $rows ['lname'];
            $fname = $rows ['fname'];
            $mname = $rows ['mname'];

            // note the .= appends data to the original $output
            $output .=  " <a href=edit.php?id=".$output."> Edit</a><br /> Last Name: ".$lname."<br />First Name: ".$fname."<br />Middle Name: ".$mname."<br /><br />";
        }
    }else{
            // note the .= appends data to the original $output
            $output .= "No results";
    }

}

print $output // This will now output all itterations of the MySQL data loop.
```

## NOTE

```
 <a href=edit.php?id=".$output.">
```

This is adding the whole string (`$output`) to the id GET clause, and is incorrect. What you want here would be some sort of `id` counter; such as

```
<a href=edit.php?id=".$rows['id'].">
```

Comment: I tried this, but the results multiplied/doubled every person. is there something in the id=" .$output. "> that makes the result has been doubled?

Comment: @Mark does my **NOTE** explain that issue?

Answer (score 2):

the problem was that you were linking to a page with incorrect id, you should specify the link with a number to edit the row, I just added $id to route to correct page. good luck

```
if( $resultSet->num_rows > 0){
while($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc())
{
    $lname = $rows ['lname'];
    $fname = $rows ['fname'];
    $mname = $rows ['mname'];

    $id = $row['id'];

    $output =  " <a href='edit.php?id=$id'> Edit</a><br /> Last Name: $lname<br />First Name: $fname<br />Middle Name: $mname<br /><br />";
}
}else{
    $output = "No results";

}
```

Comment: Tell the problem if you're answering the question friend. Just saying some problem is not an answer you need to describe the issue in the code with a comment in code or in description.

Comment: the problem was that you were linking to a page with incorrect id, you should specify the link with a number to edit the row, I just added $id to route to correct page. good luck

Comment: I'm not the poster second you should have done this in your answer not in comments.

Comment: The problem is the result, and only provides with 1 hyperlink and the other results Edit link doesn't enable the hyperlink.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to provide an `id` value for the URL:

```
if( $resultSet->num_rows > 0){
    while($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $id = $rows['id'];//something like this
        $lname = $rows['lname'];
        $fname = $rows['fname'];
        $mname = $rows['mname'];

        $output =  " <a href=edit.php?id=$id> Edit</a><br /> Last Name: $lname<br />First Name: $fname<br />Middle Name: $mname<br /><br />";
    }
    }else{
        $output = "No results";

    }

}
```

Comment: i tried this and i got a different error :Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$fname' (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: @Mark did you forget your `;` at the end?

Comment: I think that's the error you get when you're missing a semicolon at the end of the line above the referenced error text.  But I don't know what kind of `id` the `edit.php` page wants for its first argument.  The code I offered was just an example - the ID you need could possibly be elsewhere.

Comment: @Martin Nope, i already checked if im missing some semi colons.